# php - How reliable is HTTP_HOST, and will it work for search bots?

Tags: php

I have numerous domains and rather than create content for each one individually, I'm using the following code in each index.php page to display the relevant page from another site I own (where 'getDomain' is a function for getting just the domain from a url):

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$domain = getDomain($domain);
$crawl = "http://example.co.uk/page.php?domain=$domain";
$request = curl_init($crawl); 
print curl_exec($request); 
curl_close($request);
?>
```

Anyway, my questions are 1) is it reliable to use HTTP_HOST like this and 2) will search engine bots index my page or will they just get an error?

My hunch is that I'm better off entering the domain name into each index.php page - but I'd rather not have to do that!

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hmm. Am I missing something, or are you basically implementing Apache's [name-based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) ( [virtual hosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) ) yourself here?

Comment: not intentionally (I wouldn't know how)

Comment: I am almost baffled you came up with this scheme to share files. Why not just have them all mirror a single domain that has the switch in the index file? Most hosts even have this as a one click option in their panels. You just need to handle the domain content in the code. I would absolutely not curl your content. Because it is not a client side request, it will probably be indexed as expected, unless the output is handled by javascript or something.

Comment: totally not related, but you don't need to print curl_exec; unless you set the returntransfer option, it will do that for you, so your `print` statement is actually printing null while `curl_exec()` is dumping the result of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work ok (and for search engines too), but can be realy slow... If you content and design not differs in diferent domains, better way is to configure normal web-server virtualhosts for that